# Reverse effect of tab in visual studio

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, and I was wondering if there is any keyboard shortcut that does

*the reverse effect of* <kbd>tab</kbd>

Comment: The thing is, this not only works for Visual Studio but most other text editors as well. I use it often.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

if you're talking about e.g. tabbing the code to indent it, then

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>

Comment: You could also select some code then go to Edit > Advanced > Format Selection

Comment: @codinfreak - I still don't understand what your question says or how dave managed to get the right answer. I'm just saying something else you could use as well as the keyboard shortcut

Answer (score 3):

DaveDev beat me to it you can use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> to move code inversely to what tab would do to the code.

As an extra bit of detail about formatting, you can also use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to format the entire document which may save you time, or if you have a specific selection such as a `if` statement highlight it and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Happy formatting!

**Edit:** to do the keyboard keys, do <.kbd>CTRL<./kbd> but remove the periods.

Comment: Be aware the format keys do vary depending upon the chosen VS environment settings, e.g. General developer vs C# developer, so it can be CTRL + K + D, rather than CTRL + E + D

Comment: Yeah, it had me confused when I was thumping hard on the K D keys and nothing was happening ... finally sussed the reason  :-)

Answer (score 1):

try this combo to reverse tab effect

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>